# Why does VS Code's intellisense seem inaccurate for this function that returns string | null?

Tags: typescript, intellisense

I have some simple code that sometimes returns a `string` and other times `null`, for example:

```
const getNameOrMaybeNull = () => {
  // Should have a 50% change of returning false / true
  const isFeelingLikeIt = Boolean(Date.now() % 2);
  if (isFeelingLikeIt) {
    return null;
  }
  return "steve";
};
```

The function should return `string | null`. However the hover-over tooltip for VS Code shows the following inferred type:

[image: vscode tooltip]

In real life I'd have proper return types on functions, but why does VS Code say it will only return string?

`tsconfig.json` is empty, i.e.:

```json
{}
```

I have also restarted VS Code.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253646/discussion-on-question-by-mikemaccana-why-does-vscodes-intellisense-seem-inaccu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check VS Code's own settings enable **Strict Null Checks**:

[image]

As VS Code mentions, this may be overridden by `tsconfig`, so check `compilerOptions.strictNullChecks` is `true` is `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    // Enable otherwise intellisense will give odd results for functions that return null | somethingElse
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  ...
}
```

Credit to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz).